# Form Requests validation with dingoapi

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

When I extends dingoapi FormRequest class in my CustomRequest class, for the "message" field I get this default message.

```
 {
  "message": "422 Unprocessable Entity",
  "errors": {
    "email": [
      "The email has already been taken."
    ]
  },
  "status_code": 422
}
```

How can I override this message field?

Comment: https://github.com/dingo/api/wiki/Errors-And-Error-Responses

Answer (score 3):

At your `Form Request` class, you can override the method called `messages` and place your messages there according to each rule:

```
public function messages() {
       return [
            'name.required' => 'Please, provide me with your name',
            'email.required' => 'Email address is mandatory',
            'email.unique' => 'This email is already in our database'
        ]
    );
}
```